# mongoimport JSON from Google Cloud Storage in an Airflow task

Tags: google-cloud-storage, airflow, mongoimport

It seems that moving data from GCS to MongoDB is not common, since there is not very much documentation on this. We have the following task that we we pass as the `python_callable` to a Python operator - this task moves data from BigQuery into GCS as JSON:

```
def transfer_gcs_to_mongodb(table_name):
    # connect
    client = bigquery.Client()
    bucket_name = "our-gcs-bucket"
    project_id = "ourproject"
    dataset_id = "ourdataset"
        
    destination_uri = f'gs://{bucket_name}/{table_name}.json'
    dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(project_id, dataset_id)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_name)

    configuration = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()
    configuration.destination_format = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON'

    extract_job = client.extract_table(
        table_ref,
        destination_uri,
        job_config=configuration,
        location="US",
    )  # API request
    extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.

    print("Exported {}:{}.{} to {}".format(project_id, dataset_id, table_name, destination_uri))
```

This task is successfully getting data into GCS. However, we are stuck now when it comes to how to run `mongoimport` correctly, to get this data into MongoDB. In particular, it seems like `mongoimport` cannot point to the file in GCS, but rather it has to be downloaded locally first, and then imported into MongoDB.

How should this be done in Airflow? Should we write a shell script that downloads the JSON from GCS, and then runs `mongoimport` with the correct `uri` and all the correct flags? Or is there another way to run `mongoimport` in Airflow that we are missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write shell script to download from GCS. You can simply use the [GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/823b3aace298ab13d2e19b8f0bf1c426ff20407c/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_local.py#L29) then you can open the file and write it to mongo using the [insert_many](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/8c42cf1b00c90f0d7f11b8a3a455381de8e003c5/airflow/providers/mongo/hooks/mongo.py#L154) function of the MongoHook.

I didn't test it but it should be something like:

```
mongo = MongoHook(conn_id=mongo_conn_id)
with open('file.json') as f:
    file_data = json.load(f)
mongo.insert_many(file_data)
```

This is for a pipe of: BigQuery -> GCS -> Local File System -> MongoDB.

You can also do it in memory as: BigQuery -> GCS -> MongoDB if you prefer.

Comment: This makes sense. I haven't used hooks at all in my Airflow project thus far, but I'll give this a try. 

I was previously using `PythonOperator` and `pandas`, by querying the data from BigQuery into a pandas dataframe, and then `insert_many`'ing into MongoDB, which (I think) was all in memory. I am looking to (a) avoid out of memory issues and (b) improve the speed of my pipeline, which is why I'm now trying to do BigQuery -> GCS -> MongoDB without using pandas dataframes as intermediary.

Comment: There's an `s3_to_mongo` hook, but it seems like there's no `gcs_to_mongo` hook, which is a bummer.

Comment: I was also going to use `mongoimport` instead of python's `mongo.insert_many` function, hoping that it would improve the speed of the insert into our mongo cluster

Comment: @Canovice I didn't see s3_to_mongo in airflow repo. Maybe you are looking on someone custom code? As for your questions: (a) the way to avoid memory issues is to do as less stuff in memory which means go with GCS -> Local File System -> MongoDB. I don't know your pipe but usualy ETLs are not just about moving stuff it's also about transforming so it's your call if you want to transform on GCS or on local disk. There is also `GCSFileTransformOperator`. (b) speeding ETLs can come from many areas.can you parallel tasks? For example do you copy only 1 file or is it several? consider dynamic tasks.

Comment: We handle the `T` in `ELT` after the matter. The `T` happens with a tool that transforms data in our BigQuery database, before transferring to Mongo.

Comment: [https://github.com/airflow-plugins/mongo_plugin/blob/master/operators/s3_to_mongo_operator.py](here's) the S3 to Mongo Operator I was referring about.

Comment: @Canovice This is not the official airflow repo. This is a repo belongs to Astronomer. They shared some of their custom operators to help the community. I think the ELT you are describing is relatively simple. the "hard part" is just the  Local File System -> MongoDB which is something you need to write on your own - or more precise you just need to leverage the hook abilities.

Comment: so unfortunately i have also been unable to create a successful mongo connection for the `MongoHook`... any thoughts on - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64865387/setting-mongodb-connection-with-airflow