# Setting MongoDB connection with Airflow

Tags: mongodb, database-connection, airflow

According to Astronomer docs [here](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/connections/):

[image]

Despite this, I'm still not quite sure how to structure the JSON in Extras for this. I've tried:
`{ uri: mongodb+srv://myuser:mypass@my-cluster.dwxnd.gcp.mongodb.net/mydb?retryWrites=true&w=majority }` in the Extras but that doesn't work:

[image]

It seems like this should be obvious, yet I am struggling. What's the correct way, using our MongoDB URI from MongoDB Atlas, to create this connection in Airflow?

Answer (score 2):

This setup worked for me in MongoDB Atlas. **Extra** part is important as it adds `mongodb+srv` to the final connection URI. Make sure you have provider package installed (http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-mongo/stable/index.html).

Conn Id: `mongo_connection`
Conn Type: `MongoDB`
Host: `cluster0.mtfak.mongodb.net`
Schema: `MyDatabaseName`
Login: `myuser`
Password: `mypass`
Port: empty
Extra: `{"srv": true}`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would try:

0. Conn Type: `mongodb+srv` (or `mongodb`)
1. Host:`my-cluster.blahlah.mongodb.net`,
2. Login: `<username>`, Password: `<password>`.
3. Schema: admin (or your authDB)
4. The JSON object is as simple as this

```
{ retryWrite:true, 
  <field>:value, 
  w:majority
}
```

Comment: perhaps the schema is the database name?

Comment: Still not having luck.

After I input any value into the `password` field and click save, and then return back to the connection, the `password` field is set to empty each time...

Comment: `menu->admin->connections` is where I am inputting all of this information. Using `mongo_conn_id` as the Connection ID name.

Comment: I think I got it, will post solution once I am 100% certain

Comment: the last thing I can think of is MongoDB replaced by `mongodb+srv` but can't find anything else tbh.